# Why am I suddenly unable to refresh idToken with Firebase REST API in an AS3 AIR Android Project.?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage

I have integrated Firebase Authentication and Storage using [this](https://github.com/PhantomAppDevelopment/firebase-as3) guide and it was working just fine. Yesterday suddenly, I am unable to get to refresh the token. Every time I call the `refreshToken(idToken)` method, I get a `400:Invalid Id Token` error.

I didn't change the code. I was testing the app one day and it was working fine, I checked that same app the next day and it wasn't working. I have no idea what to do. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is the code I am using to refresh the token:

```
    private function refreshToken(idToken:String):void
    {
        trace("refreshing id token");
        var header:URLRequestHeader = new URLRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

        var myObject:Object = new Object();
        myObject.grant_type = "authorization_code";
        myObject.code = idToken;

        var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("https://securetoken.googleapis.com/v1/token?key="+FIREBASE_API_KEY);
        request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
        request.data = JSON.stringify(myObject);
        request.requestHeaders.push(header);

        var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
        loader.addEventListener(flash.events.Event.COMPLETE, refreshTokenLoaded);
        loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, errorHandler);
        loader.load(request);   
    }
```

Comment: you should use this api when (getDay() % 2 == 0) lol,

Comment: @payamsbr .. What do you mean?

Comment: forgive me, i just kidding! you said this code works in a day! and then does not works in the next day!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase recently changed the way you get an access_token.

I have updated the guide to reflect the changes, you now need to add an extra parameter when logging in.

```
private function login(email:String, password:String):void
{
    var myObject:Object = new Object();
    myObject.email = email;
    myObject.password = password;
    myObject.returnSecureToken = true; <-- New parameter

    var header:URLRequestHeader = new URLRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

    var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyPassword?key="+FIREBASE_API_KEY);
    request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
    request.data = JSON.stringify(myObject);
    request.requestHeaders.push(header);

    var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(); 
    loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, errorHandler);
    loader.addEventListener(flash.events.Event.COMPLETE, signInComplete);
    loader.load(request);               
}
```

In the response you will now get a refreshToken, you must exchange it for an access token with the following function:

```
private function refreshToken(refreshToken:String):void
{
    var header:URLRequestHeader = new URLRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

    var myObject:Object = new Object();
    myObject.grant_type = "refresh_token";
    myObject.refresh_token = refreshToken;          

    var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("https://securetoken.googleapis.com/v1/token?key="+FIREBASE_API_KEY);
    request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
    request.data = JSON.stringify(myObject);
    request.requestHeaders.push(header);

    var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    loader.addEventListener(flash.events.Event.COMPLETE, refreshTokenLoaded);
    loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, errorHandler);
    loader.load(request);   
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot for the answer. Highly apreciated. I reviewed your guide and now everything works fine. Only one problem, when signing in using email and password, I dont get a refreshToken in the response if the mail is already registered. Instead I get an IdToken